# Caliburn.Micro - OnDeactivate Not triggering

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm having a strange issue, and im pretty much at my wits end trying to work it out.

I have a Conductor which activates and deactivates viewmodels used for editing data, these view models implements screen and use OnDeactivate to ensure that any changes are saved before closing.

However for some reason, OnDeactivate in one of my ViewModels is never called, even tho i can see it being passed to DeactivateItem of the conductor.

To do this have the following in my conductor:

```
    private void SwitchScreen(Screen viewModel)
    {
        DeactivateItem(ActiveItem, true);
        ActivateItem(viewModel);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ProjectActionRegion);
    }

    public override void DeactivateItem(IScreen item, bool close)
    {
        base.DeactivateItem(item, close);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ProjectActionRegion);
    }
```

This ensures that when TryClose is called the region is correctly updated. The SwitchScreen is called each time a selection is made on a datagrid, loading the viewmodel. I can see that Deactivate item is called when i change selection, and i can see its passing the correct viewmodel into that method.

However OnDeactivate is still never called, and i have no idea why :/

```
    protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("SAVE ME!");
    }
```

Edited to remove incorrect code (the base. was a mistake, this is my actual code)

EDIT:

I've just realized what the difference between the working versions and the broken version is. I have a view/viewmodel that works as a conductor, this works fine. However inside that viewmodel i load a second view/viewmodel that also works as a conductor, this one fails to work, i wonder if it has to do with with being inside another conductor (but not actually handled by that conductor, just loaded into that viewmodel)

Comment: please show the declaration of your Conductor class , I'm interested in
how u inherit from Conductor base class.

Comment: I simply inherit like this: public class ProjectPanelViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>

Comment: so it's Not Conductor<IScreen>.OneActive()  , 

override Deactivate and see if you reach the breakpoint .

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. As you can see above i already override DeactivateItem and yes the breakpoint is hit as mentioned i can see the object is passed to base.ondeactivate. However that objects OnDeactivated is never called, which is my problem

Comment: If it's reached then what do you mean by NOT Deactivated ?

on a specific ViewModel which is the ActiveItem at some point, you call Deactivate and don't reach the Brakepoint ?

Comment: No, what i mean is, what i detailed above. The viewmodel IS deactivated by the Conductor using DeactivateItem however the method OnDeactivate is never called on that viewmodel.

Comment: oo.. Show the declaration of that ViewModel

Comment: Again pretty simple its : public class ProjectActionUpdateViewModel : Screen

Comment: i wanted to see if its a screen

Comment: Yes, i wouldn't be able to override OnDeactivate otherwise :P. the really odd thing is that this exact same code works for another conductor and screen setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For screen life-cycle to function correctly, all of the view models in your view hierarchy must be conducted. You should make your child conductor an active screen of your parent conductor.

You can either do this by making it the active item of the parent conductor, or by using the `ConductWith` method on the child conductor, passing in a reference to the parent conductor.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i seem's i forgot to click submit on the comment, this worked perfectly using ConductWith, thank you very much.